# How to keep running a loop when calling a subprocess into it

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I created a Python script which reads a txt file `check.txt` and depending on its content (the words 'start' or 'stop') launches or kills another python script named 'test.py'.

This is the code:

```
import psutil
import time
from subprocess import call
   

while True:
    with open('check.txt') as f:
        order = f.readline()

    with open('pid.txt') as f:
        pid = int(f.readline())

    if order == 'stop':
        if psutil.pid_exists(pid):
            os.kill(int(pid), 9)

    elif order == 'start':
        if not psutil.pid_exists(pid):
            print('Starting script')
            call(["C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe", "test.py"])

    print('Checking again in 10 secs...')
    time.sleep(10)
```

This is the `test.py` script:

```
import time
import os


pid = os.getpid()
with open("pid.txt", "w") as f:
      f.write(str(pid))    
cont = 0    
while True:
    cont += 1
    print('This script is running ' + str(cont))
    time.sleep(5)
```

If `test.py` is running already, when I write 'stop' in the text file `check.txt` the script works as expected killing the process and it keeps checking the txt for a new instruction.

My issue is when `test.py` is not running and I launch it writing the word 'start' in the text file. The script starts okay `test.py` but the loop does not work anymore because once entering into the subprocess `call(["C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe", "test.py"])` line it never goes out from there.

Any idea how can I execute the subprocess `call` line and keep the loop running after it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) instead as it is not blocking

also you should get rid of psutil, `process.returncode` is None when the process is running, so you can use that instead of psutils.

```py
import time
from subprocess import Popen

process = None
while True:
    with open('check.txt') as f:
        order = f.readline()

    if order == 'stop':
        if process is not None and process.returncode is None:
            os.kill(process.pid, 9)

    elif order == 'start':
        if process is None or process.returncode is not None:
            print('Starting script')
            process = Popen(["C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe", "test.py"])

    print('Checking again in 10 secs...')
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Probably don't use signal 9 unless you know that other, more friendly signals can't work (in which case, probably solve that bug in the called script).

Comment: @tripleee that depends on whether a cleanup is needed,  i'd probably send signal 2 (interrupt) to gracefully terminate the application if a cleanup is required, but it's not required here.

Comment: Great! Popen did the trick! 

However, I need to keep using psutils instead of process.returncode because when I do several operations of 'start' and 'stop', it does not work properly, it throws some kind of permission errors (probably my fault). Just changing Popen into my original code, it works like a charm.